# How to add NOT NULL constraint for column in Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm creating a table in Cassandra key space, i want to add NOT NULL constraint for one column in table. I've googled for that but didn't find any answer.
Does Cassandra supports all functions supported by Relational Databases?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to add that constraint? This would defeat the purpose of the "new" storage engine where you can dynamically add columns to tables. However, back to your question you can specify WITH COMPACT ENGINE when creating the table. That will effectively force you to insert a value in all the columns of the table.

BTW, Cassandra is a very different beast. It is not a relational database, you should look carefully at your requirements before everything else.

Comment: thanks. I've WITH COMPACT ENGINE it is working but my table consists of many columns and some of them can be null. COMPACT ENGINE forcing to insert a value in all columns

Comment: So I'm afraid there's no solution to your problem then. You cannot force cassandra to force a client to insert a value in a specific column. Boring, but that's how it works... You could however write a middleware that performs this check. Annoying, but that's how it works...